# Combining wordpress and static html

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, directory-structure

I ran into a bit of a problem today. A client of mine had a Wordpress site build, she asked me to build a new static website (html5,css,js,no wp) but have a link to the old wordpress site containing a webshop she liked to keep.

So I wanted to put my new files in the same folder, but index.php was already doing something for the wordpress site. Being the front of the WP application.

I'm not that familiar with WP, so I can't really fiddle around with it too much myself. But all the URL's for the webshop seem to pass by this file (index.php). I also have another WP site, which is a blog, in another folder. This is how my file structure looks like.

public_html

```
   -index.php
   -/shop/  -->wordpress
   -/blog/  -->wordpress
   -newsite.php
   -/img/
   -/css/
   -/js/
```

So on my newsite.php i have a link to the directory /blog/ , but since index.php is already part of the wordpress site, it catches the url and redirects to an error page of the old wordpress site, instead of just going in the directory.

What are my options here? I tried moving the shop and index.php into a folder together and referring to that folder on my newsite.php on the link for the shop, but it just gave an access denied error.

Thanks in advance

site's online at http://www.tutuchic.be/

Comment: Why not simply host the static site outside the wordpress root ?

Answer (score 0):

i think You use a mod_rewrite rule to url redirect

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^indexs.php$ newsite.php/blog/ [R=301,L,NC]